# Guarantee of variable value fetched from provider

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic-native

uid is declared in the class using uid=this.auth.getuid();

auth is injected in the constructor.

this.uid is then used in ionViewDidLoad() method.

My question is - whether the assignment of uid=this.auth.getuid() is guranteed to get the value from the injected provider immediately before it is used in ionViewDidLoad() method? OR should I have written the uid=this.auth.getuid() in the constructor? or in the ionViewDidLoad() method as the 1st line?

The way I have initialized the uid varialbe is at class level, not in constructor nor at ionViewDidLoad(); what is such a declaration called? and when is this invoked?

[image: code image]

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869992/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-ionviewdidload-function

Comment: It is not recommended to put anything in constructor. Initialize the variable in`ngOnInit` instead

Comment: The way I have initialized the uid varialbe is at class level, not in constructor nor at ionViewDidLoad(); what is such a declaration called? and when is this invoked?

Comment: @SachinGupta please advise on above comment