# Where to call IONIC SQLLITE select statement

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I have a DB function as shown below:

If I want to use the results of this query in a page module, where do I call this function? Do I call it in the constructor or the lifecycle method (ionViewDidLoad, ionViewDidEnter). Please advise.

Currently I call it in the constructor but it seems like it slows down the app. I am not sure if I am doing the right thing

````
 getAddressDetails() {

 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

 let sql = "select * from tablename"
 this.database.executeSql(sql, []).then((data) => {

 resolve(data)}
   });
 }```
````

Answer (score 0):

> (...) main difference between the `constructor` and the `ionViewDidLoad`
>   (...) is that sometimes you want to interact with the DOM (maybe to
>   initialize a map).
>
> In that case, if you try to access the DOM in the `constructor`, you
>   will notice that the DOM is not ready by that point and you won't be
>   able to get the map element. The correct approach to do it would be
>   inside the `ionViewDidLoad` (...).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39871448/939803) answer.

> `constructor` is called before all, once per instantiation of the
>   page, here you can do initialization that does not refer the HTML DOM
>
> `ionViewDidLoad` is called when the page DOM has been loaded, before
>   than the page is shown, also a single time per page instantiation,
>   here you can do initialization thet needs the HTML DOM to be ready

And see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49048320/939803) answer.

Comment: Got you @Filipe , from what I understand, it is not really wise to do heavy stuff(Loading around 2000 records from the DB) on the constructor itself. Is that right?

Comment: If you have a lot of records, try pagination. Or use some technique of lazy loading list items. Look [this](http://masteringionic.com/blog/2018-02-13-lazy-loading-images-and-managing-lists-with-ionic-virtualscroll/) article.